# How to maintain cell attribute in slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid

I am creating a grid in which a cell with the value "Y" should be green and a cell with value "N" should be red. To do this I have assigned a cssClass "YN" to the cells and I have created an attribute containing the value of the cell. It looks something like this:

CSS:

```
.slick-cell.YN[val="N"]{...
```

grid cell:

```
<div class="slick-cell l10 r10 YN" val="N">N</div>
```

This works great but as soon as I scroll or sort, the attribute is destroyed and does not reappear when the element is recreated.

I need a way to get the cell value and create an attribute each time the element is created. Perhaps there is an easier way than creating an attribute? Can the CSS directly reference the div html?? Any help would be most appreciated.

PS: slickgrid is awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the grid is scrolled,sorted or changed page the grid DOM is recreated. So all the attributes you applied are lost...you have to apply them again..

so you need to recall your code in `onscroll` and `onsort` functions..

```
grid.onScroll.subscribe(function(e) {
            grid.invalidate();
            grid.render();

            yourCodeToStyleAgain();

        });

 grid.onSort.subscribe(function(e) {
            grid.invalidate();
            grid.render();

            yourCodeToStyleAgain();

        });
```